# Is there a solution for dual partitions that grow towards each other?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, virtualization, cloud

Taking form how programs use their available memory. With the heap and the stack starting in opposite ends of address space and then growing towards each other.

Is there a similar solution for disk partitioning?

Like defining two partitions on a disk, the first partition defined as usual, but the second with its beginning defined as the end of the disk and it's end defined as the end of the first partition.

That would allow me to define as small first partition and allow to reallocate it's size into the second partition, since the second partition would be larger and it's end usually wouldn't contain any data.

Comment: *"Is there a similar solution for disk partitioning? "* -- Apples and oranges.  RAM is used as volatile storage, whereas disk is mass storage and must be non-volatile.  There simply is no dynamic sizing of disk partitions or (non-volatile) filesystems.

Comment: Well, there kind of is - APFS dynamically allocates volume sizes within a container.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- Okay, so Apple did something weird with another layer of allocation for *"APFS-formatted volumes"*.  But for MBR/GUID partitions, I'm positive my comment is accurate.  IOW note the `windows-10` tag.

Comment: Can potentially be done using 3rd party software - https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/ - I'm not actually proposing it as a solution, just mentioning that one very new partitioning method does seem to achieve something similar to what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Tetsujin *"Can potentially be done using 3rd party software"* -- That software clearly indicates that it only provides read-only access from Windows to APFS.

Comment: meh... ok, I'll stick to my Mac then with its potential to do all of the above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not exactly like you envision it.

Windows 10 will create a number of smaller partitions at the front.  Especially if you are use UEFI.

However you can create a C: less than the whole drive.  Leaving as much free space as you desire.  Further you can extend (and in some cases even shrink the drive) the c: drive from disk management in windows 10.  These options do have some limitations.

You can also create a partition at the end of the drive, but it will not work as you envision it.

The end will be at the end, and the beginning sector would be at a lesser position.  Also to extend the drive you would have to move the entire contents back the desired amount of GB, and then extend the partition into the create free space.

There are offline partitioning software that will let you move and resize partitions at will.

However, none of the existing solutions allow the partition to run backwards.

That means you would have to write the code yourself, and run it through a rigorous testing to make sure it doesn't cause data loss/corruption.  There are unused partition type that you could temporarily use during the development stage, but this is years of work.  You would have to convince the existing stake holders to allow the drivers to bundle your drivers with their OS.

Comment: Would that also be true if the second partition were a Linux partition? I guess it would be "easier" to get a driver to store data "backwards"

Comment: It would be easier to design, and implement.  Your only hope for an easier implementation is to learn assembly, and create a hard drive firmware.  Let pretend you have a drive starting 700m(illion) sectors and ending at 950m sector.  You must take the logical sector 0 (700m in our case), and  if sector>700m apply special math (950m-(logical sector))  Further you would have to compute the logical sector #, subtract, and convert back to the physical sector and then send back the contents of the corrected sector number. Along with rigorous testing, to make sure it always works correctly.

Comment: Practically hopeless then :P  But it sure would be a nice feature. Thanks

Comment: @GxFlint Unless you befriend an assembly language programmer.  Accessing the hard drives firmware, just requires a JTAG plug. https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/04/hard-disk-firmware-hacking-part-1.html

Comment: @cybernard *"if sector>700m apply special math (950m-(logical sector))"* -- Your cheap scheme only works if restricted to single sector access (and really doesn't even require HDD firmware hack  since it can be done in the driver). (This is from someone who has done disk controller firmware.) Modern OSes use reads/writes of multiple consecutive sectors at a time for improved throughput.  Only using single sector access is a disastrous performance penalty.

Comment: @sawdust   Single sector access would be bad.  However, if your buffer contains 100 sectors, you subtract 100 more sectors, and then write the 100 sectors in a burst like you always do.  It would take more math to actually get it functional, but with enough time it could be done. if >700m (950-(physical sector-700m))-(<Buffer size>)/512( or 4096 depends).

Comment: *"...then write the 100 sectors in a burst like you always do."* -- Wrong!  There's a sector-order problem: everything in the computer system expects a certain ordering of sectors.  That's what single sector access has to solve, or else you perform a lot of reordering by copying in memory.  It's the same problem of simultaneously dealing with liitle-endian and big-endian byte order sources.   You should have kept your answer simple and to what you understand.  You're delving into a hack when you don't grasp the *obvious* pitfalls.